# How to import gmsh geo file in fipy

Tags: fipy

this question is probably due to my lack of knowledge of python, nonetheless here it is: is it possible to import a gmsh mesh file.geo instead of writing it entirely on the fipy script as is it done in this tutorial ?

http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.circle.html#module-examples.diffusion.circle

a procedure like this:
open file;  read/store the content in data_var; mesh = Gmsh2D(data_var) # generate the mesh with gmsh

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to "read/store the content in data_var".

Per http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#module-fipy.meshes.gmshMesh, the first argument to Gmsh2D et al. is:

> arg: a string giving (i) the path to an MSH file, (ii) a path to a
>   Gmsh geometry (”.geo”) file, or (iii) a Gmsh geometry script

Just supply the path to your .geo file.